# Intersecting GEOMETRYCOLLECTION with POLYGON

Tags: python, shapefile, shapely, voronoi, pyshp

I am using Shapely to intersect geographical data and Pyshp to write the results to a shapefile. I don't completely understand how "intersection" works.

First, I create some points and calculate the Voronoi polygons this way:

```
# (1)
from shapely import LineString, MultiPoint, Point, Polygon, MultiPolygon
from shapely.geometry import shape
from shapely.constructive import voronoi_polygons
from shapely import intersection
import shapefile

output_shapefile = "/tmp/simple_test_01.shp"
points = MultiPoint([Point(1,1), Point(2,2), Point(4,3), Point(2,4), Point(2,5), Point(6,5), Point(5,4), Point(7,1)])
myVoronoi = voronoi_polygons(points)
#>>> myVoronoi
#<GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (POLYGON ((-5 -5, -5 4.625, -4.5 4.5, 0 3, 4 -1, 4 -5, -...>
n = 0
with shapefile.Writer(output_shapefile, shapeType=5) as w:
    w.field("ID", "N")
    for geom in myVoronoi.geoms:
        w.shape(geom)  
        w.record(n)
        n += 1
```

When I draw the shapefile on ArcMap, I get this (green points highlighted by me, not in the shapefile):

[image]

I create a polygon with which I will intersect the Voronoi polygons:

```
# (2)
polygon_to_intersect = Polygon([Point(0,0), Point(2,8), Point(4,3.7), Point(10,4.5), Point(5,-4), Point(0,0)])
output_shapefile = "/tmp/simple_test_02.shp"
with shapefile.Writer(output_shapefile, shapeType=5) as w:
    w.field("ID", "N")
    w.shape(polygon_to_intersect)  
    w.record(1)
```

On ArcMap it is like this (shown with red outline):

[image]

I perform the intersection:

```
# (3)
intersected = intersection(myVoronoi, polygon_to_intersect)

>>> intersected
<POLYGON ((0.6 2.4, 0.75 3, 1.125 4.5, 2 8, 3.553 4.66, 3.739 4.261, 4 3.7, ...>

output_shapefile = "/tmp/simple_test_03.shp"
n = 0
with shapefile.Writer(output_shapefile) as w:
    w.field("ID", "N")
    w.shape(intersected)  
    w.record(n)
```

simple_test_03.shp is a single polygon. Its vertices can be seen here:

[image]

I was expecting "intersection" to give me the Voronoi polygons intersected with polygon_to_intersect. However, I am getting polygon_to_intersect with new vertices, in the places where the polygon's exterior intersects the Voronoi polygons.

```
>>> intersected
<POLYGON ((0.6 2.4, 0.75 3, 1.125 4.5, 2 8, 3.553 4.66, 3.739 4.261, 4 3.7, ...>
```

"intersected" is a Polygon instead of a MultiPolygon, why?

However, if I do this:

```
# (4)
output_shapefile = "/tmp/simple_test_04.shp"
multipol = []
for geom in myVoronoi.geoms:
    multipol.append(intersection(geom, polygon_to_intersect))

n = 0
with shapefile.Writer(output_shapefile) as w:
    w.field("ID", "N")
    for pol in multipol:
        w.shape(pol)  
        w.record(n)
        n += 1
```

I get this result, which is what I wanted in the first place:

[image]

Each colored area is a Voronoi polygon intersected with "polygon_to_intersect".

Why do I need to do (4) to get what I want, when I was expecting (3) to work that way?
Is it the fact that myVoronoi is a GEOMETRYCOLLECTION instead of a POLYGON or MULTIPOLYGON?

I tried to convert myVoronoi to a MultiPolygon prior to the intersection:

```
# (5)
output_shapefile = "/tmp/simple_test_05.shp"

myVoronoi2 = MultiPolygon(myVoronoi)
>>> myVoronoi2
<MULTIPOLYGON (((-5 -5, -5 4.625, -4.5 4.5, 0 3, 4 -1, 4 -5, -5 -5)), ((-5 1...>

intersected2 = intersection(myVoronoi2, polygon_to_intersect)

>>> intersected2
<POLYGON ((0.6 2.4, 0.75 3, 1.125 4.5, 2 8, 3.553 4.66, 3.739 4.261, 4 3.7, ...>

n = 0
with shapefile.Writer(output_shapefile) as w:
    w.field("ID", "N")
    w.shape(intersected2)  
    w.record(n)

>>> intersected2 == intersected
True
```

but the result is the same as in (3).

This is a simplified example. In my real situation, "myVoronoi" has 18000+ polygons and "polygon_to_intersect" is much bigger. (3) is not working as I want and (4) works but has performance issues.

**[EDIT]**
This is my real situation. My Voronoi polygons:
[image]
Some zoom in:
[image]
Some more zoom:
[image]

And this is my "polygon_to_intersect" (outline in orange):
[image]
With some zoom:
[image]

As mentioned by @Pieter, the intersection works with "union semantics", which means my Voronoi polygons get unioned away first, and then intersected with my polygon_to_intersect.

But that is not what I want. I want this (each Voronoi polygon in the result file; some of them intersected at the polygon_to_intersect boundaries):
[image]

So I used this code:

```
output_shapefile = 'intersected.shp'
n = 0
w = 0
i = 0
skipped = 0

with shapefile.Writer(output_shapefile) as writer:
    writer.field("ID", "N")
    for poly in myVoronoi:
        n += 1
        if not (n % 500):
            print(f'Processed {n}, within = {w}, intersected = {i}, skipped = {skipped}')
        # If the Voronoi polygon is fully inside polygon_to_intersect, don't waste time intersecting
        # Just write the polygon into the output file
        if within(poly, polygon_to_intersect):
            writer.shape(poly)
            writer.record(n)
            w += 1
        else:
            # Perform the intersection
            intersected = poly.intersection(polygon_to_intersect)
            if intersected:
                writer.shape(intersected)
                writer.record(n + 50000)
                i += 1
            else:
                skipped += 1
```

This works fine but it took almost 25 minutes to complete. There are 18.600+ polygons in myVoronoi and polygon_to_intersect has several hundreds of thousands of vertices.

Pieter's suggestion of using a Rtree didn't help much here in terms of performance.

```
tree = shapely.STRtree(voronoi_polys)
intersecting_idx = tree.query(polygon_to_intersect, predicate="intersects")
intersections = shapely.intersection(voronoi_polys.take(intersecting_idx), polygon_to_intersect)
```

Because it performs many more intersections than in my code above.

So I went and created a much simplified "polygon_to_intersect":
[image]

which has only 76 vertices.

And modified my code:

```
# Read the new simplified shapefile into memory
simplified_file = 'simplified.shp'
with shapefile.Reader(simplified_file, shapeType=5) as w:
    for shapeRec in w.shapeRecords():
        polygon_to_intersect_simplified = shape(shapeRec.shape)
        prepare(polygon_to_intersect_simplified)


output_shapefile = 'intersected.shp'
n = 0
w = 0
i = 0
skipped = 0

with shapefile.Writer(output_shapefile) as writer:
    writer.field("ID", "N")
    for poly in myVoronoi:
        n += 1
        if not (n % 500):
            print(f'Processed {n}, within = {w}, intersected = {i}, skipped = {skipped}')
        # If the Voronoi polygon is fully inside the simplified shape, don't waste time intersecting
        # Just write the polygon into the output file
        if within(poly, polygon_to_intersect_simplified):
            writer.shape(poly)
            writer.record(n)
            w += 1
        else:
            # Perform the intersection with the real (not simplified) polygon
            intersected = poly.intersection(polygon_to_intersect)
            if intersected:
                writer.shape(intersected)
                writer.record(n + 50000)
                i += 1
            else:
                skipped += 1
```

"within" is computed 18.600+ times against the much simplified polygon, which is faster. Polygons within are not intersected, so time is saved there.
Then, those polygons not "within", are intersected with the real polygon_to_intersect.

The modified code runs in under 4 minutes.

Without the simplified polygon:

- within = 16257
- intersected = 2357

With the simplified polygon:

- within = 13669         <--- very fast against the simplified polygon
- intersected = 4945     <--- more intersections than the previous code but overall the execution time goes from 25 minutes to 4 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing overlays with GeometryCollections the inner boundaries are (intentionally) first unioned away, so this result is to be expected ([source](https://github.com/libgeos/geos/issues/1059)).

It should be possible to solve the performance issue of the loop by using an rtree index, as shown in the following code sample:

```
import numpy as np
import shapely
from shapely import MultiPoint, Polygon
points = MultiPoint([(1,1), (2,2), (4,3), (2,4), (2,5), (6,5), (5,4), (7,1)])
myVoronoi = shapely.voronoi_polygons(points)

polygon_to_intersect = Polygon([(0,0), (2,8), (4,3.7), (10,4.5), (5,-4), (0,0)])

voronoi_polys = np.array(myVoronoi.geoms)
tree = shapely.STRtree(voronoi_polys)
intersecting_idx = tree.query(polygon_to_intersect, predicate="intersects")
intersections = shapely.intersection(voronoi_polys.take(intersecting_idx), polygon_to_intersect)
print(intersections)
```